# how to implement PATCH HTTP Method without using EF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

How can i implement PATCH HTTP method without using Entity framework in order to apply some partial update to a resource(s) ? i'm using dapper for my data access but i dont know how to implement PATCH only using Dapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Adding JSON Patch To Your ASP.net Core Project

Step1. Install-Package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch/)

Step2. implement HttpPatch action

```
[HttpPatch("update/{id}")]
public Person Patch(int id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Person> personPatch)
{
    Person person = _personRepository.GetById(id); // Get person object from the database via Dapper.
    
    personPatch.ApplyTo(person); //Apply the patch to that Entity. 
    
    _personRepository.Update(personDatabase); //Update your entity in the database via Dapper. 

    return personDatabase;
}
```

[JsonPatch in ASP.NET Core web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/jsonpatch?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

> Simple example

1. Get the entity from db _personRepository.GetById(id)

   {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Michael"
   }
2. Apply the patch to entity

   [
   { "op": "replace", "path": "/name", "value": "Tony" }
   ]

   Get new entity

   {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Tony"
   }
3. Then update all fields of entity in `_personRepository.Update(personDatabase)`.

Comment: how would you implement "_personRepository.Update(personDatabase)" to only update fields that changed value ?

Comment: `_personRepository.Update` could update all fields. I posted a simple example for u to understand how it update.